# How does svn store merge info in commit? Is this a bug?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, merge, version-control, tortoisesvn

I merged some commits from FeatureBranch A to FeatureBranch B in IntelliJ.

I went to feature B. Had it up to date with repositotry and merged it by *merge from...* -> feature A
Merging was more or less straight forward.. After succesfully running all tests I commited with IntelliJs proposed comments.

---

svn property svn:mergeinfo now has the following information added to the specific line.

*2431-2435,2438-2439,2450,2471-2472*

When I view the history in IntelliJ or Tortoise there are two revisions missing 2471 and 2472.

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot]
[image: Tortoise Screenshot]

---

Those two revisions have been merged correctly nonetheless. It's just that they are missing in the said history view, which can lead to quiet some confusion.

If this is a bug.. is it IntelliJ or svn related? 
How does svn link merge information to a certain commit? it can't be just svn:mergeinfo 
It is quite difficult to google anything helpful, maybe someone around here has some experiences.

svn version is 1.9.5.1210

IntelliJ version is 2017.2.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this happen even after you refresh the checkout (via `svn update` or whatever stands for this in your GUI tools)?

Comment: @kostix, yes it does.

Comment: I'd consider this a bug then, yes. (Of course if you really can see a proper `svn:mergeinfo` value using the stock `svn` CLI tool (which can be though of as being "reference").

Comment: yes, `svn propget svn:mergeinfo` also shows all the revisions I'd expect there.
I'll ask the JetBrains guys if there might be a bug regarding their _commit_ invocation of the svn tool.

Comment: I'd say it appears that the bug is more likely in running the `svn status` (or whatever) or parsing its results. Well, just guessing ;-) I support the idea to ask JB folks.